# moving multiple files from text to multiple destinations

Tags: batch-file

Hi I am trying to move multiple files to separate directories.  I am also using a list in a txt file.

In txt file I have

```
123
123_a
123_b
321
321_a
321_b
```

In a seperate folder the files reside as
123.txt
123_a.txt
123_b.txt
etc...

I want the filenames with _a to go in one direction, filenames with _b to go another, and without the _a or _b to go somewhere else.  I know how to use an exlude list so moving the plain ones isn't an issue. Its getting just the _a files to move somewhere.  I think I need to use an IF or Stringsrc somehow but I havent been able to get it.  I must use %src_folder% in the command since its a networked folder.  And only certain filetypes are allowed in this folder.
Any help is appreciated!

simple copy command I'm using, I'll be using tokens and delims later:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (C:temp\test.txt) DO xcopy "%src_folder%\%%i.txt" "%dst_folder%"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help in a basic way: make sure the folders exist first

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (list.txt) do (
   echo %%a|find /i "_a" >nul && move "*%%a*" "d:\folder1"
   echo %%a|find /i "_b" >nul && move "*%%a*" "d:\folder2"
   if exist "*%%a*" move "*%%a*" "d:\folder3"
)
```

Comment: Looks like what I want.  Ran it through and it looks right.  But it says it can't find the file.  I'm guessing I have source folder in the wrong location.

Let me clarify another thing.  The list in the list.txt is referencing other files(that are not .txt).  Lets say theyre jpeg files, in another folder. So this is what I have:
for /f "delims=" %%a in (list.txt) do (
   echo %%a|find /i "_a" >nul && move "%%a.jpg" "%src_folder%"
   echo %%a|find /i "_b" >nul && move "%%a.jpg" "%src_folder%"
   if exist "%%a" move "%%a.jpg" "%dst_folder%"
)

folders are already set.

Comment: I edited the code and added the wildcards - the `list.txt` and `batch file` goes in the `folder with all the files`.  The list.txt should have unique identifiers for the files.

Comment: ah, I can't have the batch and list.txt in the same folder as the files though.  Anyway to set the source folder?

Comment: You haven't explained why not.  If it's a special set if circumstances then it's wise to include the details in your initial question.

Comment: updated.  It's a networked drive that multiple people use.  Only certain file types are allowed in this folder otherwise it'll get deleted.

Comment: If you supply the details then I can see about adding them.

Comment: There is a very large depository of files.  All files with unique identifiers(8 numerical digits).  There are three types per identifier, the plain, _a and _b.  There are thousands among thousands of files in this depository.  I get requests for files that are in a list, could range anywhere from 5 files to 100 files per list.  I get multiple lists a day to go to different clients.  When I pull these files, the files with _a and _b need to be processed differently.  Every folder I'm using is networked in some way. Some won't allow other filetypes(seperate program doing this).

Comment: I need the paths, I need to know if access by credentials is needed, I need to know if all the files are in a single folder.

Comment: I am using 'set src_folder' command, credentials are already set in the script I have and both are working.  All the files should be in one folder(network path) if not, could be in another(network path).

Comment: I found out a solution.  I create a new text list.  In the batch file I use find and send all the _a, _b to the new list and then run a batch to process those differently.